# Apostrophe-CMS Schema Image

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been trying to find a good way to handle images inside of schema's, and was wondering if there's a built-in way that I've been missing. The end goal is to have a schema field where a user can select an image from the image library (as opposed to a plain attachment upload), while being able to use the crop tools and options (size, ratio, etc) that are usually used in apostrophe-image-widgets. I'm currently using a joinByOne with type apostrophe-image to make this somewhat work, but cropping is unavailable and I can't specify aspect ratios, as far as I can tell. This is the current schema definition I'm attempting to use:

```
{
    name: '_storeImage',
    label: 'Store Image',
    withType: 'apostrophe-image',
    type: 'joinByOne',
    help: 'The image that will show on the main store page.'
}
```

If nothing else, is there a way to pass options into apostrophe-image to restrict aspect ratio and enable the cropping tool, or is that only available in the widget editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `apostrophe-images-widgets` widget to select the image

```
{
  name: 'myImage',
  label: 'Image',
  type: 'singleton',
  widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
  options: {
    aspectRatio: [ 4, 3 ],
    minSize: [ 400, 300 ],
    limit: [ 1 ]
  }
}
```

Configure the options as you want them and look in the original `apostrophe-images-widgets/views/widget.html` to see how to implement the image in your schema's template.